# IBM MQ Configuration

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, websphere-mq-ams

I need help with configuring the following :

I have a Server A that have both Remote and local Queue with a Queue manager 1 and there's a Server B that have also Remote and local Queue with a Queue manager 2.
The two servers doesn't belong to the same network.

What I need is to configure an already installed IBM MQ server in server A so I can receive messages from server B and at the same time send messages to server B.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is basic queue manager to queue manager connectivity.  Go look up any introductory MQ documentation or YouTube video.  i.e. You will want sender & receiver channels between the 2 queue managers.

Comment: How can i implement this configuration with Requester-server channel ?

Comment: You can do it with Sender/Receiver channel pair or Requester/Server channel pair.  Just follow any Introductory MQ document.  Note: 95% of the channel pairs use Sender/Receiver, using Requester/Server channel pair requires more overhead, so you should have a real valid reason for using them.

Comment: If you have MQ administrators you can ask them to configure connectivity channel between QM1 and QM2. I assume QM1 QR pointing to QL at QM2 and vice versa. You might need QA for QR so that local MQI client could refer it send/recieve MQMessage.

If you insist can read MQ manual of how to configure channel between 2 remote QMGR.

Comment: Your question stated "The two servers doesn't belong to the same network."  Can you update your question to expand on that?  Do you mean that one queue manager is on your companies network and the other is at a different company external to you, or are these just two different "subnets" on your companies network where the servers can communicate in a unrestricted fashion?  Based on your inquiry about RQSTR/SVR and the AMS tag I am guessing the former.  If that is the case please add details about how you connect between your companies (ex: internet, circuit, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Given the following queue managers:

- Qmgr name: QM1 host: qm1.company.com port: 1414
- Qmgr name: QM2 host: qm2.company.com port: 1414

Run these commands on QM1:

1. DEFINE CHANNEL(QM1.QM2) CHLTYPE(SDR) CONNAME('qm2.company.com(1414)') XMITQ(XMIT.QM2) MAXMSGL(4194304) DESCR('')
2. DEFINE CHANNEL(QM2.QM1) CHLTYPE(RCVR) MAXMSGL(4194304)
3. START CHANNEL QM1.QM2
4. START CHANNEL QM2.QM1

Run these commands on QM2:

1. DEFINE CHANNEL(QM2.QM1) CHLTYPE(SDR) CONNAME('qm1.company.com(1414)') XMITQ(XMIT.QM1) MAXMSGL(4194304) DESCR('')
2. DEFINE CHANNEL(QM1.QM2) CHLTYPE(RCVR) MAXMSGL(4194304)
3. START CHANNEL QM2.QM1
4. START CHANNEL QM1.QM2